# How to place a connection string in an env file

Tags: docker, .net-core, environment-variables

I have a .net core application to be dockerized. Along with it is an env file where I am trying to define a connection string with the following format:

`Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=myDb;Uid=root;Pwd=root;allow user variables=true;SslMode=none;maxpoolsize=100;Convert Zero Datetime=true;`

I have tried the following two in env file with no success:

`connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=myDb;Uid=root;Pwd=root;allow user variables=true;SslMode=none;maxpoolsize=100;Convert Zero Datetime=true;"`

`connectionString='Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=myDb;Uid=root;Pwd=root;allow user variables=true;SslMode=none;maxpoolsize=100;Convert Zero Datetime=true;'`

Comment: I had to break that connection string into parts so that I can place them in my env file. And it's working now

Answer (score 1):

file approach were you using, but I recommend using named env-files, so you can differentiate, you can follow this example:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file

Create `myenv-dev.list` file with your env var definition let say for your ***dev*** environment, and a subsequent one for all your environments - dev/test/uat/prod, eg:

```
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=dev
connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=myDb;Uid=root;Pwd=root;allow user variables=true;SslMode=none;maxpoolsize=100;Convert Zero Datetime=true;"
...
```

And then pass this to docker - let's say with a `printenv` to validate this:

```
docker run -it --env-file ./myenv-dev.list microsoft/aspnetcore printenv
```

And then as a results would look something, like for all your *case-sensitive* environment variables:

> ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=dev 
>   connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=myDb;Uid=root;Pwd=root;allow user variables=true;SslMode=none;maxpoolsize=100;Convert Zero Datetime=true;"
>
> ...

If you wish to implement this with a compose file, you can do this in your `docker-compose.yml` file as well per environment:

```
version: '3'
services:
  myservice:
    image: 'microsoft/aspnetcore'
    env_file:
     - ./myenv-dev.list
```

See more examples at:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option

On the other hand you may want to consider using a secret-management system like `AWS Parameter Store` or `Secrets Manager` later to store your database passwords and other sensitive info at a safe place and fetch those dynamically with something like pstore:

- https://github.com/glassechidna/pstore